# Firebase Firestore displaying [object, object] instead of document data. How to fix?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that takes in user input and uploads to firebase firestore. When i retrieve the documents from the firestore to display on another page on the app using a component  it is displaying [object, object] the data i enter to firebase manually is displaying. I am unsure how to fix this any suggestions would be helpful.

```
      export interface Item{
        id?: string, 
        createdAt: number,
         title: string,
       description:string,
       carType:string,
       typeID: number,
       color: string,
       colorId: number
       }

   //item.service.ts
   export class ItemService {

    //property of items collection
    itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;

     items: Observable<any[]>;


   constructor(public fsDb: AngularFirestore) { 
     this.items = this.fsDb.collection('complete- 
       entry').valueChanges();

    }

     getItems(){
     return this.items;
      }
     }

   //items.component.ts
     export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

        items: Item[];
     constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items=>{
           console.log(items);
         
           this.items = items;
            })
             }}
      //items.component.html

         <div *ngIf="items?.length >0;else noItems">
           <ion-list *ngFor="let items of items" class="collection">
        <ion-item class="collection-item">
          <strong>{{items.title}}: </strong>{{items.description}}  <br>
         </ion-item>

         </ion-list>
       </div>
       <!-- if there are not items display -->
   <ng-template #noItems>
        <hr>
     <h5>There are no items to display</h5>
   </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the console.log is displaying the data in the console.
What you are missing to display your items in the template is :

1. Loop over the items with an **ngFor*

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
...
</ng-container>
```

2. Inside that, interpolate and access the desired properties

```html
{{ item.id }}
{{ item.createdAt }}
// Or even the whole object just to check
{{ item | json }}
```

So, to recap, in your template you have for example :

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    Item title : {{ item.title }}
</div>
```

By the way, you can assign *this.fsDb.collection().valueChanges()* to the *items* property when declaring it in the service and use it directly from your component with no problem.

You can test here (just set your Firebase app config in the AngularFireModule import) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-67126446?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I should have added the html before as i have this already and while it is showing data i manually entered into the database it isnt showing the nested data collect from the user and uploaded to firestore. It is displaying [object, object] instead of the data. I edited the post to reflect the html i have

Comment: If the problem resides in the input data from a form, you should provide us with some context. Are you able to show a screenshot of a data sample from Firestore?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the data structure in firestore. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well first of all the data doesn't match with the Item interface you gave. What I see is { arousal: { arousal: Array<string>;  };  title: { Activities: string; Description: string; } }.
Maybe you made a mistake in your form (double *arousal* ?), or you should check the properties called in the template.

Comment: yes my apologies i copied in code i was trying on stackblitz. i have tried with the link you gave with the data matching. and it is sill returning [object,object]. i believe because i am trying to access the array in complete-entry document

Comment: I guess so. Try to debug with the json pipe, it is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help you helped me realise the issue was the upload of the form i uploaded it as a array which caused the issues. I have extracted the details i needed from the form created using formBuilder and now it is working.